# Excel - Assign value if specific text is found

Tags: excel, excel-formula

so i have a spreadsheet and i need to perform a rather basic function, but i can't get it to work using nested "IF", i just need to assign a value to a cell, if another specified cell contains specific criteria:

-The function needs to count 0 if cell is empty

-The functions needs to assign value of 1 to cell if defined cell contains the letter "L"

-The function needs to assign value of 2 to cell if partial word "keyword" is found on cell

i tried using

```
    '=IF(D5="",0,IF(D5="*L*",1,IF(D5="*keyword*",2)))'
```

so basically if:

-D5 is empty, E5 should be "0"

-D5 contains the letter "L", E5 should be "1"

-D5 contains the word "keyword", E5 should be "2"

using the above formula, it successfully applies "0" to the cell E5 when D5 is empty, in any other condition, it just shows "FALSE", any tips how i can accomplish this? in advance, thank you.

Comment: what is your version of excel?

Comment: My version of excel is 2013

Comment: Wild cards are not recognized as such in equalities such as you show.  Suggest you use `FIND` or `SEARCH` without the wild cards.  `FIND` is case sensitive; `SEARCH` is not.  They will return either a Number or an Error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. ISNUMBER AND SEARCH functions are what you need. Hope this helps. Thanks.

```
=IF(D5="",0,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("L", D5)),1,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("keyword",D5)),2,"")))
```

Comment: I tried a function using "ISNUMBER and SEARCH" before too but it quite doesn't work, the one you provided doesn't quite work either, I forgot to add that the problem i have is that the item on "D5" is from a "drop-down list", so when selecting an item, the item has the letter "L" no matter what, so the item could be "L001" OR "L001-keyword", so the formula doesn't really know which one to prioritize i guess...

Comment: The Formula will prioritise the "outer" statements first - the "Contains L" check has priority over the "contains "keyword" check.  Sounds like you need to swap those conditions to `=IF(D5="",0,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("keyword",D5)),2,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("L",D5)),1,"")))`

Comment: Chronocidal. I tested it and the order is from left to right.

Comment: Yep!, that works! the methodology works, looking for the condition backwards works great!, thanks @Chronocidal